# Flink: How can I emits the outputs immediately in the one-to-many streams' join

Tags: join, triggers, apache-flink

I have one query stream and one item stream. I want to join these two stream on the query_id, the relation is one-to-many. How can I emit the item immediately to the output stream after its arrival and get some info from the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this either using Table API and a simple [join](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/dev/table/sql.html#joins) or you could implement it yourself using CoFlatMap on stream keyed by the query_id and buffering incoming events in the state. You should consider some retention policy though, to make sure the state won't grow infinitely.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I will going to try your suggestions.